# $5\sin2a + 12\cos2a = 11$, giving all solutions in the interval $0 < a < 180.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$5\sin x + 12\cos x = 13\sin(x + 67.38)$

Solve:

$5\sin 2a + 12\cos 2a = 11$, giving all solutions in the interval $0 < a < 180.$

I solved it thus:

$0 < 2a < 360$

$13 \sin(2a + 67.38) = 11$

$\sin (2a + 67.38) = \frac {11}{13}$

Let $2a + 67.38 = b$

$\sin b = \frac{11}{13}$

$b = 57.8$

Now, I reasoned that on the unit circle, 0 to 180 degrees is positive for sine. So $b = 57.8, 180 - 57.8 = 122.2$.

I then subtracted 67.38 degrees and divided by 2, and got $a = -4.79, 22.41$.

Because $-4.79$ is out of range here, I discarded it.

These are not the answers, though. I would prefer a detailed description of where I went wrong and why, because I am a beginner and find trig very difficult at this point.

Note: All angles are in degrees.

Comment: It's better to work in radians and then finally convert to degrees, just a tip. Plus, I think you mean $13\sin(x + 67.38)$

Comment: $5\sin x + 12\cos x = 13\sin(x + 67.38)$ where did this come from? I thought you were only given $5\sin 2a + 12\cos 2a = 11$ to solve for all $0 \le a \le 180$

Comment: This came from an earlier part (i.e. I was told to rewrite the LHS into the form $Rsin (x + \alpha)$. I didn't have time to write that part out, so I just wrote it as a "fact".

Answer (score 1):

You've made a calculation error in the last step

$$a = \frac{122.2-67.38}{2} = 27.31^0 $$

Everything else in the solution is fine :)

**EDIT**

I missed something - if you look generally, you will have the following solutions

$$a = 180n - 4.79^0, 180n + 27.4^0$$

Do you see how you would get two solutions?

Comment: Whew, thanks. So I have one solution to the equation. The answer sheets say the answers must be ($\theta = 27.4$) and ($\theta = 175.2$). Now I can't figure out how to get 175.2!

Comment: It's $180-4.79$.

Comment: But I got - 4.79 degrees after I had already converted $2a+67.38$ into $\alpha$.

Comment: okay, I got the correct solutions using the formula you posted. Basically, after I do all those calculations and solve for $a$ itself, I still need to do $a=180n−4.790,180n+27.40$? 
And do those "formulas" change for cos or tan? I'm really sorry, I know these are basic questions, but I'm trying to clarify the exact general methods so I can apply them to any problem like this (and remove gaps in my understanding). Also, why do we still want to do the $a=180n−4.790,180n+27.40$?

Comment: So you find the general solution - since these functions are periodic, any solutions in one interval will be repeated after a period - from this general solution you pick the solutions of interest